# How can create a auto report in to Google Sheet with the metrics is an Event Label?

Tags: google-analytics, metric

How can create a auto report in to Google Sheet with the metrics is an Event Label?

Comment: this might be a question better suited for: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you should state what you have tried, and what error you encountered. (i have no expertise in google-analytics, i am trying to help you get better answers by improving the question)